# Mathematical Functions python code check

Tags: python

Hey all im in a intro to python class and so far enjoy it and cant stop practicing. I have what I think the exercise is asking for. One question I have is where I start listing the variables like sum, difference, product and so on. Im using Sublime Text and they all come out white except for sum, why is that? Is that going to mess with things even though when I run the code numbers seem to be accurate?

```
''' Write a program that prompts the user for two integers and then prints 
'''sum, difference, product, average, distance, max and min.

import math
number1 = float(input("Please enter an integer: "))
number2 = float(input("Please enter another integer: "))
print()
print()
sum = number1 + number2
difference = number1 - number2
product = number1 * number2
average = (number1 + number2) / 2
distance = abs(number1 - number2)
maximum = max(number1, number2)
minimum = min(number1, number2)

print("Sum between the two:",sum)
print("Difference between the two:",difference)
print("Product between the two:",product)
print("Average between the two:",average)
print("The distance between the two:",distance)
print("The maximum between the two:",maximum)
print("The minimum between the two:",minimum)
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `sum` is a builtin function in Python, you should change this name if you need to use it next

Comment: You would receive a `TypeError` somewhere down the line if you decide to use the inbuilt `sum` function when your custom defined variable overwrites it.

Comment: ahh okay well that makes sense. How about the code itself? Distance, max and min look okay?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 and its running fine, you might want to recheck, and `sum` is a predefined function in python, mught want to avoid the variable with same name, also remove the top quotes and those lines

Comment: @Matticus, `maximum/minimum` are ok, the builtin function are `max/min`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that `sum` comes out in your text editor is the fact that [it is a function name](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) as well. Therefore, should you wish to use this function later on in the code, it would raise an exception.

A couple of notes to your code:

There is no need to `import math` if you do not use it.

`'''` marks the beginning and the end of the comment. To comment out a single line, use `#`. Your comment at the beginning should be:

```
'''this is a multiline comment
and here it continues'''

# this is a single line comment
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your feedback. As far as my distance, max and min code, thats all done properly? I kind of went with what I remembered in class and this is what I came up with.

Comment: @Matticus Yes, even the `sum` would be working, the only thing that is happening is that you cannot use `sum()` function down the line, which is why it is considered bad practice.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I completely understand now.